# Service is down status

Tags: status

What is the best practice to inform users if the services is down? In my example it's an application upload function that may be over capacity.

Thanks.
Uli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that this can be accomplished and it all depends on what best fits your particular application.

If all you are looking to do is disable a feature, like in your example of disabling the upload feature, you could put a prominent message at the top of that page that says that it is not currently available and then disable the upload button on that page.

If you plan to take down the whole site for maintenance, it's good to have it as a separate page that is not linked to the rest of your site in any way.  That way you can modify anything within your site, and also make a lot of changes to your web server.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback! What happens if my server is completely down (Because of a DDOS attack for example) and I link to a Posterous blog at **example.posterous.com** that usually "redirects" over DNS to **blog.mywebsite.com**? Does the blog show up?

Comment: No, you'd be pretty much screwed.  But if your error page is a simple HTML page like Arran suggested it would be a lot harder to take that page down as well with a DDOS attack.

Answer (score 1):

Have an error page that is pure HTML - that way if the database goes down, you are not showing an error page that is dependant on some kind of DB query. Otherwise, your error page, will error.

Answer (score 0):

You could return an [HTTP error code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) if it is a web/http upload endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In our company, we have a procedure that do something like that (on our apache server):

- Stop a particoular service
- Enter .htaccess and do a rewrite-url to a standard down page

When we came back:

- Enter .htaccess and remove the rewrite-url
- Restart services

This is done by a bash script called when we want to shut down some services.

You could do that with a demon that check if server is "overlogged" and starts that routine.